# Provide unique values to each instance of a submit button

Tags: php

I have a table where I'm assigning unique values to multiple inputs, (for example):

```
<td><?= $PMComments ?><input name="PMComments[]" type="text" value="<?= $PMComments ?>"></td>
```

Each row in my table that is brought in from my SQL database receives a unique number - PMComments1, PMComments2, etc...  For some reason this is not working with my Update button:

```
<td><input name="update[]" type="submit" id="update" value="Update"></td>
```

Why is that?

```
for ($n = 0, $t = count($_POST['PMComments']); $n < $t; $n++) {
$UpdateValue             = $_POST['Update'][$n];
$PMCommentsValue         = $_POST['PMComments'][$n];
$LineID                  = $_POST['LineID'][$n];
echo "UpdateValue of $UpdateValue " . "with comments $PMCommentsValue " . " with LineID " . $LineID . "<br>";      
}
```

I get an echo of

```
UpdateValue of with comments TEST with LineID 11414
```

Am I not able to assign unique values to a button or something?

Comment: Only the `<button>` pressed gets submitted, therefore you will only ever get at most one button value.

Comment: Each submit must have its own form.

Comment: Besides the above, if this did work as you expected, the value of `$UpdateValue` would always be the string `Update` so i dont really see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to give each instance of the update a unique value, so I can only update ONE line at a time.  Right now (later on in the code) I have an SQL statement, but that statement updates every single row in my table.  i want it to only update the line that I've clicked "update" on.

Answer (score 0):

if you're up for using some jquery.  here's what i would do:

1. make a generic clickable button or fontawesome icon and assign the unique id to that button
2. when that button is clicked, grab the data from the related input
3. do an ajax post call to post the form
4. consider flashing something on the ui to mark that the save was complete like

it would work something like this (generic syntax)

```
<td><input id='PMComments1' value='...'></td>
<td><button class='submitit' id='submit1' data-id='PMComments1'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button></td>
...
<td><input id='PMCommentsN' value='...'></td>
<td><button class='submitit' id='submitN' data-id='PMCommentsN'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button></td>

<script>
 $('table').on('click', '.submitit', function() {
    var id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var val = $('#'+id).val();
    $.post("/my/ajax/handler.php", { id: id, val: val }, function () {
        // do ui update tweak here like dim the save button until the next time
    });
});
</script>
```